# Algorithm for moving a point towards the origin under constrained motion within a variable plane

Tags: geometry

A point has position $L(t)$ in 3D space. The point's velocity is constrained to directions within a plane that has a unit normal direction $D(t)$.
$D(t)$ changes with time, its motion is smooth but unpredictable to the algorithm. The algorithm has access to $D(t)$, and its 1st and 2nd time derivatives.

I would like to design an algorithm that smoothly moves the point closer to the origin over time, utilising the changing direction vector.

For the trivial case where $D$ is perpendicular to $L$ and unmoving, the point can be moved with velocity $v(t)=-kL(t)$, exponentially moving the point closer to the origin.

For the case when $D$ is not perpendicular to $L$ the algorithm can not directly move $L$ to the origin, so it must utilise the motion of $D$.

I'm not sure if such an algorithm is possible without knowledge of $D(t)$ in the future. Any advice will be gladly received, thanks.

Comment: How about just projecting $-kL(t)$ into the subspace orthogonal to $D(t)$?

Comment: This does work but is very slow at moving $L$ to the origin, especially as gain $k$ gets higher.

Comment: Why is that? Do you mean as $k$ gets smaller? Also, couldn't you normalize the velocity vector to achieve whatever speed you want?

Comment: When $k$ has a small magnitude the velocity of $L$ is small, but also when $k$ is large, $L$ quickly moves to a position in line with the normal direction $D$, preventing it from moving to the origin because $L$ stays out of the plane. I want an algorithm that tries to keep $L$ within the plane, allowing it to progress to the origin. I don't want to normalise the velocity (but could if the solution requires), as this problem is linked to a control theory problem, where $L$ represents an objects angular momentum and $v$ the torque applied. Thanks for your responses so far Karl.